# achartenginge manual legends and labels

Tags: achartengine

I developed an app for Android using achartengine for some charts.
I have 68 XYseries in my chart, but I want to have only 2 Legends. All XYSeries in red = one legend. All XYSeries in green = second legend.

Also I need manual Labels for the Y Axis. Y=1 should be g for example.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have a chart generated with the achartengine (achartengine.org). In this combined chart are 68 different XYseries. My Problem is, normaly each XYSeries got an own legend. But this is to much. I only want two legends under the chart. One for all red XYSeries and one for all green XYSeries.

Comment: Here you can see a picture from the chart http://db.tt/XGuwR5R5

Comment: And instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 I need g, a, h, c, d labels at the y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `setShowLegendItem(boolean showLegend)` method in `SimpleSeriesRenderer`, so it is inherited by `XYSeriesRenderer`. You should call this method for most of your renderers excepting 2 of them.

In order to have custom Y axis labels, you need to do the following for each such lavel:

```
renderer.addYTextLabel(y, "text");
```

And you also need to disable the default labels:

```
renderer.setYLabels(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's unbelievable how many functions achartengine has. A very good library

Comment: Now I have another problem. I want only my manual y axis labels. At the moment there are the manually y-axis labels and all the standard labels. I don't want standard labels at x or y axis. @Dan

Comment: You can see an actual screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1wz1bxzxaijfuv/Screenshot_2013-08-26-08-13-40.png

Comment: Please read again the last paragraph in my answer. Use renderer.setYLabels(0);

Comment: Hello @Dan, i have a new problem with AChartEngine using Android Studio. Can you please help me again because I think you are an expertise for AChartEngine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082161/achartengine-combinedxychart-wrong-4th-parameter-found