# AChartEngine CombinedXYChart wrong 4th parameter found

Tags: android, android-studio, achartengine

i have a little Problem with my combined chart. 3 years ago i made the same with Eclipse and used a jar library. I copied my code to android Studio, using a dependency and now it's not working. I can't get it work.

I will post my whole code and then I will mark the problem.

```
public void createChart()
{
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    final Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    couchdurations = extras.getLongArray("couchtimes");
    perstdurations = extras.getLongArray("persttimes");
    //ToDo Sqlite noch ergänzen
    XYSeries couchseries = new XYSeries("CouchBase");
    XYSeriesRenderer couchRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeries perstseries = new XYSeries("PerstDB");
    XYSeriesRenderer perstRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    couchRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    couchRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.X);
    couchRenderer.setFillPoints(false);
    couchRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    couchRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);

    perstRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    perstRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.X);
    perstRenderer.setFillPoints(false);
    perstRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    perstRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);

    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(couchRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(perstRenderer);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0.0);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(10000000.0);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(60000.0);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(40);
    multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(40);

    for(int i = 0; i < couchdurations.length; i++)
    {
        couchseries.add(couchdurations[i], datasizes[i]);
        perstseries.add(perstdurations[i], datasizes[i]);
    }
    dataset.addSeries(couchseries);
    dataset.addSeries(perstseries);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    // Specifying chart types to be drawn in the graph
    // Number of data series and number of types should be same
    // Order of data series and chart type will be same
    String[] types = new String[dataset.getSeriesCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i < (dataset.getSeriesCount()); i++)
    {
        types[i] = LineChart.TYPE;
    }
    // Creating a combined chart with the chart types specified in types array


mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);
    // Adding the Combined Chart to the LinearLayout

    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}
```

The problem is the following line:

```
mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);
```

I always get the error that the 4th parameter is wrong. But I used originally the same code before 3 years inside another android app. 
[Error Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svhIt.png) 
[Error Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otDSe.png)
You can see the Error Message in the attached pictures. 
Wrong 4th parameter type. Found 'java.lang.String[]', required: 'org.achartengine.chart.CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]'

Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Wrong 4th parameter type. Found 'java.lang.String[]', required: 'org.achartengine.chart.CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]'
You can see it in the attached Screenshots

Comment: I don't see any screenshot. Anyway, the APIs have changed, so just do what the error says, change String[] to CombinedXYChart definitions.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/svhIt.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/otDSe.png
Here you can see the Screenshots (marked in my post)

Comment: I got it. Changing from
String[] types = new String[dataset.getSeriesCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < (dataset.getSeriesCount()); i++)
        {
         types[i] = LineChart.TYPE;
        }
to

CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] types = new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]
                {

                        new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 0), new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 1)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Changing from

```
String[] types = new String[dataset.getSeriesCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i < (dataset.getSeriesCount()); i++)
    {
        types[i] = LineChart.TYPE;
    }
```

to

```
CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] types = new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]
            {

                    new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 0), new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 1)
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

With this link [github.com/hdodenhof/achartengine](https://github.com/hdodenhof/achartengine) also combined Time-Series succeed. Then the following code works with CombinedTimeChart ...:

```
    CombinedTimeChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] types =
            new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] {
                    new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(CubicLineChart.TYPE, 0),
                    new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 1),
                    new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 2),
                    new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(BarChart.TYPE, 3)
    };

    mChart = getCombinedTimeChartView(this, dataset, multiRenderer, types);
```